# How do I add numbers that have been inputted in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, addition

So, my code is allowing the user to input 2 numbers, `num1` and `num2`. However the addition function is concatenating the numbers rather than adding them. How can I fix this please?

Here is a snippet of the function:

```
var sum= num1 + num2;
alert(`Sum of ${num1} and ${num2} is ${sum}`);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` is of type *string*. That's why the string concatenation is happening. To perform arithmetic operation, you have to convert the value to number.

Change

```
var sum= num1 + num2;
```

To

```
var sum= Number(num1) + Number(num2);
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because the even though the input type is number the value is in form of a string, and instead of adding it, it will concating the values.Convert them to number before adding it

```
var sum = Number(num1) + Number(num2);
alert(`Sum of ${num1} and ${num2} is ${sum}`);
```

Comment: numbers can be double

Answer (score 0):

you need to cast strings to numbers, `+` sign is concatenating strings, here are the examples

```
var sum= Number(num1) + Number(num2);
alert(`Sum of ${num1} and ${num2} is ${sum}`); // Sum of 1 and 2 is 3
```

or

```
var sum= +num1 + +num2;
alert(`Sum of ${num1} and ${num2} is ${sum}`); // Sum of 1 and 2 is 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force it to string and use `"" + num1 + num2`

```
var sum = "" + num1 + num2;
alert('Sum of ${num1} and ${num2} is ${sum}');
```

Answer (score 0):

An other idea is to use parseInt()

```
const sum = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2)
console.log(`Sum of ${num1} and ${num2} is ${sum}`)
```

here a working code

```js
let num1 = 50
let num2 = "5" //in case of string value the value will be converted by parseInt()
const sum = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2)
console.log(`Sum of ${num1} and ${num2} is ${sum}`)
```